# Como obtener en Detalle Vista valores relacionados en 4 Modelos Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

Tengo 4 modelos en mi proyecto, Producto, Pedido, DetallePedido y Venta, lo que quiero lograr es que en DetalleVista de mi Venta, mostrar los productos del Pedido cancelado, en Venta almaceno el id del Pedido, y cada DetallePedido contiene los productos que estan relacionados con Pedido.
Estos son mis Modelos:

```
class Pedido(models.Model):
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    fecha = models.DateField(default=datetime.now, null=True, blank=True)
    estado = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='Pendiente')
    cliente = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='Agregue Cliente')
    observacion = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, default='Ninguna')

class DetallePedido(models.Model):
    pedido = models.ForeignKey(Pedido, db_column='pedido_id', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    producto = models.ForeignKey(Producto, db_column='producto_id', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, verbose_name='Productos')

    cantidad = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=0, default=1)
    precio = models.CharField(max_length=200, default=0)

class Venta(models.Model):
    fecha = models.DateField(default=datetime.now, null=True, blank=True)
    pedido = models.ForeignKey(Pedido, db_column='pedido_id', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    total = models.CharField(max_length=200, default=0)
    cliente = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    nit = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

En DetalleVista de cada Pedido obtengo los prodcutos de ese pedido de esta manera:

```
{% for producto in pedido.detallepedido_set.all %}
 code..
```

Pero en Venta no se como lograr conseguir mostrar todos los productos de la misma manera, alguna sugerencia o ayuda de como podria lograrlo?

**Edit:**
Mi DetailView de Pedido:

```
class PedidoDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Pedido
```

y de Venta:

```
class VentaDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Venta
```

Comment: A que te refieres con mostrar los productos de la misma manera en Venta? No entiendo bien la pregunta la verdad.

Comment: @Vichoko En la vista detalle de pedido, ahi puedo mostrar todos los productos relacionados a ese pedido, quiero hacer eso pero en Venta, donde paso el id del Pedido

Comment: Tienes algo de lógica en views.py? No tengo mucho de donde ayudarte la verdad porque falta información crítica. Sin embargo, puedo notar que tu modelo de datos podría mejorarse. Por ejemplo, si creo entender bien la semántica de tu modelo, parece que la mayoría de las relaciones ManyToOne que haces con ForeignField deberían ser relaciones OneToOne, por ejemplo en pedido y detallepedido, y entre pedido y venta. Si son todas OneToOne tal vez podrías condensar tu modelo en 2 o incluso 1 modelo y se simplificaría mucho el retrieval, en especial si casi siempre quieres los campos de los 3 al final.

Comment: Para Detalle no, simplemente le mando el modelo al DetailView, puedes observar hice un edit a la pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo he conseguido de la siguiente manera:

```
{% for producto in venta.pedido.detallepedido_set.all %}
  code..
```

Simplemente se me ocurrio probar agregandole "venta", y ha funcionado, no sabia que se podia hacer de esa manera.